# Google App Engine project not starting in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-tools

I'm running a Google App Engine project in eclipse on ubuntu. 
After updating to 19.10, the project server is refusing to start in eclipse, with the following error in the error log

```
Plug-in: com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.localserver

Google Cloud SDK: Error starting server: Invalid Java SDK. /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/bin/java does not exist.

Session Data:
eclipse.buildId=4.13.0.I20190916-1045
java.version=1.8.0_151
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_IE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

the JDK is installed on my machine at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java

I've noticed that the error message has a slightly different directory,there's an extra "/bin" - /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin **/bin**/java

Does anyone know how I can fix this configuration?

(the upgrade to 19.10 probably isn't relevant, but everything was fine before the update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem
I had included the /bin in the directory of the JRE under Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs, i.e. /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin

once I changed this to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/ the servers started without a problem